# AngularJS Pagination With Bootstrap Not Displaying Next/Prev Buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am trying to paginate data I get through a JSON using AngularJS and Bootstrap. It works in that it shows only the number per page I want but the Next/Prev and numbered buttons do not show up at all. The pagination tag does not even seem to be recognized in my editor (Notepad++), I am not sure if that has anything to do with it. I am currently testing in IE. Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while - thank you!

Here is my HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NES- Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>

<body onload="getUrl()">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.html"> Admin</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="Users.html">Users</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >Search</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="sort('Username')">Username</th>
        <th ng-click="sort('Domain')">Domain</th>
        <th ng-click="sort('GivenName')">Given Name</th>
        <th ng-click="sort('Surname')">Surname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in users.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search">
        <td>{{user.Username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Domain}}</td>
        <td>{{user.GivenName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.Surname}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>

    <iframe id="iframe" src="Index.html" style="display:none"></iframe>

    <script>

        function getUrl() {
            var uri= document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('apiUri').value;
            server = uri + (uri.last === "/" ? "" : "/");
        }   

        var server; 
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : URL
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                $scope.users = response.data;
                $scope.viewby = 5;
                $scope.totalItems = $scope.users.length;
                $scope.currentPage = 1;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
                $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show

            });

            $scope.sort = function(keyname){
                $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
                $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
            }

              $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
  };

$scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
  $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
  $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
}
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the example I followed which works fine: http://embed.plnkr.co/eheFSh/

Comment: Can you make a plnkr of your current code in order to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

ui-bootstrap requires Angular and Bootstrap CSS file as dependencies. Looks like you missed out linking bootstrap css file in your code.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thank you, I added it but unfortunately the problem is still occurring.